# Cross Domain calls with Restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

The following call was working for me in AngularJS:

```
var baseUrl = 'http://aaa.com/';
return $http.jsonp(baseUrl + 'root/' + path + '?action=doit&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
```

Now, I've decided to try to use Restangular and have replaced that with the following:

```
return Restangular.all('root/' + path).getList({action: 'doit', callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'} );
```

But I get the error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm initializing Restangular as follows:

```
.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
 RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://aaa.com/');
 RestangularProvider.setDefaultRequestParams('jsonp', {callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'});
});
```

Comment: Well, your call is not being sent as a jsonp request, but I don't know why.  I'd fire up your debugger and make sure that the call happens in the way that you expect and that your params are being respected.

Answer (score 0):

To enable CORS, you have to make the following change. Don't forget that the server side needs to support CORS as well.

Inject httpProvider in your app.js and do the following.

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```